# C++ compiler not finding #include <thread>

Tags: c++, multithreading, g++

Here is the top of my source file:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <fstream>
```

...

```
thread help(startHelp);
```

Where the thread is inside the function handleRequestsFromServer and startHelp is a `void` function.

When compiling this with `g++` on Mac OS X 10.8.4, I get this error:

```
$ g++ diskutilityhelper.cpp -o run.out
diskutilityhelper.cpp:5:18: error: thread: No such file or directory
diskutilityhelper.cpp: In function ‘void handleRequestsFromServer()’:
diskutilityhelper.cpp:140: error: ‘thread’ was not declared in this scope
diskutilityhelper.cpp:140: error: expected `;' before ‘bomb’
```

I don't understand this error at all. Could anyone please help?

Comment: what version of g++ ? also have you tried compiling with the -std=c++11 option ?

Comment: Are you sure, your compiler support C++11 ?

Comment: You probably meant to use the flag `-std=c++11` to enable C++2011 mode.

Comment: @InsertNameHere does it recognize -std=c++11 or -std=c++0x sa valid options ? if so it has c++11 support you can also check the version with --version

Comment: and -std as an option for g++ doesnt work

Comment: i suppose my g++ isn't updated enough

Comment: @InsertNameHere: The easiest way to see if `<thread>` is support is trying to enable C++2011 mode using the flag `-std=c++11` or for older version of gcc `-std=c++0x`. If there is some support for `<thread>` the compiler will find, at least, the corresponding header but possible not all the desired content.

Comment: What version does `gcc -v` report?

Comment: @DietmarKühl -std isnt recognized as an option and im working on a mac if that helps

Comment: @DietmarKühl its version 4.2.1

Comment: There are both binary and source packages available for gcc. See <http://gcc.gnu.org> for download options.

Comment: @InsertNameHere That's too old. Compile using `clang++` instead from the latest XCode version. That supports C++11 just fine (AFAIK). GCC is included in XCode mostly for compatibility purposes. The recommended compiler on OS X these days is Clang.

Comment: first c++11 support is on 4.3

Comment: I don't think XCode will install a newer version for you: Apple moved away from gcc support with gcc choosing to use GPLv3. However, gcc-4.2.1 is sufficient to bootstrap the latest version of gcc. Alternatively, you might want to use `clang` instead of `gcc` which is kept up to date by updates of XCode (as far as I know; I normally compile the compilers from source anyway).

Comment: still with clang it says that it cant find thread

Comment: nevermind it works with the -std flag

Comment: Thanks everybody for your help

Comment: You might just need the `-pthread` flag, in addition to `-std=c++11`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You probably want to use Clang instead of GCC.

```
clang++ -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++ diskutilityhelper.cpp -o run.out
```

All the options for GCC can be used with Clang, some are ignored. The above links to libc++, which is the preferred C++ standard library for Mac OS X with Clang (and a lot more complete than libstdc++ (even when considering the newest GCC).

As for the reason why this happens: my magic fortune telling ball tells me the g++ you are calling is an ancient GCC 4.2.1 Apple thingie, with that GCC's libstdc++, which has little to no C++11 support. Apple switched to Clang and it is now much preferred.

Answer (score 3):

The version of GCC shipped with XCode is very old. It doesn't support C++11.

You should compile your code using `clang++` instead from the latest XCode version. That supports C++11 just fine (AFAIK). GCC is included in XCode mostly for compatibility purposes. The recommended compiler on OS X these days is Clang.

Comment: And the use of `-std=c++0x -stdlib=libc++` is *still* required. (I'm asking myself: why?...)

Comment: When you got a C++ system assuming a certain language definition and, to a lesser extend, a specific standard C++ library implementation, you don't want to break assumption, not even when switching compilers. There are semantic differences between C++2003 and C++2011 which do matter and third party libraries tend to provide a version depending on a certain version of the standard library. In case you wonder: the place I'm working at has several thousands programmers, working a system with a few hundred million lines of code and porting **is** an issue...

Comment: Yes thank you it works with those flags thank you for your support