# Why it says that #include <thread> is not included when it is included in c++?

Tags: c++, multithreading, error-correction

I am new to multithreading but I found an answer in this site about simple multithreading code. I copied it exactly with `#include <thread>` but later it says in the terminal (I am running Visual Studio Code) that I have not included thread. Here is the code.

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

using namespace std;

void task1(string msg)
{
    cout << "task1 says: " << msg;
}

int main()
{

    thread t1(task1, "Hello");

    t1.join();
}
```

This is the error I see:

```
c:\Users\Lol\Desktop\C++\Thread testing\Threadtest.cpp: In function 'int main()':
c:\Users\Lol\Desktop\C++\Thread testing\Threadtest.cpp:18:5: error: 'thread' was not declared in this scope
   18 |     thread t1(task1, "Hello");
      |     ^~~~~~
c:\Users\Lol\Desktop\C++\Thread testing\Threadtest.cpp:5:1: note: 'std::thread' is defined in header '<thread>'; did you forget to '#include <thread>'?
    4 | #include <thread>
  +++ |+#include <thread>
    5 |
c:\Users\Lol\Desktop\C++\Thread testing\Threadtest.cpp:24:5: error: 't1' was not declared in this scope; did you mean 'tm'?
   24 |     t1.join();
      |     ^~
      |     tm
The terminal process terminated with exit code: 1
```

Comment: Did you turn on C++11 or higher?

Comment: yes i did. Why?

Comment: What's the exact error messages(s) you get?

Comment: See if this helps - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17901797/c-compiler-not-finding-include-thread

Comment: `std::thread` only works in C++11 or higher.  Please post the full error message that you get.

Comment: ok here it is in pastebin: https://pastebin.com/HhVDupsu

Comment: The code is fine, it should compile with C++11 or later. The error doesn't complain about `#include <thread>` but instead about the identifier `thread` which is odd. Whatever the problem is, the cause is not shown in what you provided. Either you have an odd project configuration or the code you provided is not representative of the code that is causing the problem.

Comment: Here is the full code: https://pastebin.com/sjrUNzJy

Comment: At a guess you are using a version of MinGW that doesn't support `std::thread`

Comment: Here is my version. gcc version 9.2.0 (MinGW.org GCC Build-20200227-1)

Comment: Here you can see that the code is correct https://wandbox.org/permlink/v1BPcno7hjIj24kd The problem is somewhere else. Can you build your project from terminal?

Comment: Yes I found that it is a problem with MinGW. Probably because it is 64 bit. Do you know how to install clang. Are there any online tutorials. Thanks

Comment: I follow in installation process [similar enough to this just recommend it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30069830/how-to-install-mingw-w64-and-msys2). Never had any problems and as an added bonus msys provides an excellent ecosystem of extra tools and libraries.

Comment: Is that an installation process for clang. I already have mingw installed. I am really a noob so sorry if this is a dumb question.

Comment: Sorry, no that's a process for MinGW's g++, the clang install isn't much different. You want the mingw-w64-clang package. I'd take  its g++ package as well though. There's something a bit off with your current g++ install.